# Oracle 11g XE ignores my statment after putting value form variable in trigger

Tags: oracle

I want to get the specification from `Doctor` and `Department` tables to make sure that manager of the department is the same specification of it while inserting ..

```
create or replace TRIGGER check_dept_man
After Insert on DEPARTMENT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
spec Varchar2(30);
dept_name Varchar2(30);
BEGIN
dept_name := :new.DEPT_NAME;
SELECT DR_SPECIALISATION INTO spec from DOCTOR where DR_ID= :new.MANAGER_ID;
IF ( dept_name != spec ) THEN
raise_application_error(-20353,"error man");
END IF;
END;
```

This is the Error I get:

[image]

This is Department Table:

```
CREATE TABLE  "DEPARTMENT" 
   (    "DEPT_ID" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "DEPT_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "MANAGE_DATE" DATE, 
    "LOCATION" VARCHAR2(6), 
    "NUMBER_OF_DOCTORS" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "NUMBER_OF_NURSES" NUMBER(3,0), 
    CONSTRAINT "DEPT_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPT_ID") ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "DEPT_NAME_UQ" UNIQUE ("DEPT_NAME") ENABLE
    ) ;
```

and this is Doctor :

```
CREATE TABLE  "DOCTOR" 
   (    "DR_ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
"DR_NAME"  "FULL_NAME" , 
"DR_GENDER" VARCHAR2(6), 
"DR_SPECIALISATION" VARCHAR2(30), 
"DR_LOCATION"  "LOCATION_TY" , 
"DEPT_NO" NUMBER(3,0), 
"TOTAL_SURGERY_TIME" NUMBER(4,0), 
 CONSTRAINT "DR_GENDER_IS" CHECK (dr_gender IN ('Male','Female')) ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "DR_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DR_ID") ENABLE
  ) ;
 ALTER TABLE  "DOCTOR" ADD CONSTRAINT "DR_DEPT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPT_NO")
  REFERENCES  "DEPARTMENT" ("DEPT_ID")
```

The Whole Thing was about this ' and this .. I spent all day for this silly mistake .. Thanks @kordirko and For you all Guys

Comment: You have syntax error: `IF` statement needs to end with `END IF;`

Comment: Thanks for this remark .. but even after adding it it gives me this error 'Error at line 8: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

6. dept_name Varchar2(30);
7. BEGIN
8. SELECT DEPT_NAME INTO dept_name from DEPARTMENT where MANAGER_ID= :new.MANAGER_ID;
9. SELECT DR_SPECIALISATION INTO spec from DOCTOR where DR_ID= :new.MANAGER_ID;
10. IF ( dept_name != spec ) THEN
'

Comment: @Valijon I Edited my code Like This and still there is an error

Comment: Put the error message into your question and apply formatting.

Comment: I Putted the picture of the error @ConsiderMe

Comment: Use a string literal: `'error man'` between single quotes instead of `"error man"` between double quotes. A name between double quotes is treated as an identifier and must be declared first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for `@kordirko` observation, it should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_dept_man
    BEFORE INSERT ON DEPARTMENT
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    spec Varchar2(30);
    dept_name Varchar2(30);
BEGIN
    dept_name := :new.DEPT_NAME;
    SELECT DR_SPECIALISATION INTO spec from DOCTOR where DR_ID= :new.MANAGER_ID;
    IF dept_name != spec THEN
        raise_application_error(-20353, 'error man');
    END IF;
END;
/
```